# Symfony2 deploy - blank pages in prod

Tags: php, symfony

I've got a problem with deploying my Symfony2 app. I've got access to the server only via ftp, no command-line.
I setup the permissions via umask:

```
umask(0000);
```

I have changed permissions of app/cache, app/logs, web/myUploadFolder to "777 -R".

The problems that I can't managed are:

1. I can't upload files. Everything is OK on localhost, but in production server creating entities with files is stopped. No errors, no exceptions, no logs appears, only blank page.
2. I am getting blank page too when I set debug to true in app.php or app_dev.php:

   $kernel = new AppKernel('prod', true);

So debugging is so hard, I think the problem is in permissions... Any ideas ? Thanks in advance.

---

Edit:
I've managed to access debug mode, the answer is below: 
[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26252123/3849146)

I thought that blank page in debug mode and blank page during upload files have the same cause but probably it's not truth. I've created separated question with more details here:
[request blank page problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26251854/php-post-request-stopped-with-blank-page).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using symfony version above 2.2 to enable debug simply putting 
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', true); is not enough. Put the below line above it to properly display any php errors (most possible reason of blank page) too.
\Symfony\Component\Debug\Debug::enable(1);

One more thing I encounter is it still doesn't show function parameter mismatch error. To handle the same do a temporary change in symfony code in ErrorHandler.php, handleFatal() method and include E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR in the line where $type is checked.
This will at least shows up the error on page.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've spend a lot of time trying to understand what's going on. The problem with debugging is in my .htaacess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domena$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domena$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !web/
RewriteRule (.*) /web/$1 [L]
```

Most of sites give this solution to change your DocumentRoot, but this cause me a problem so I've deleted this lines and tried to access to app_dev.php with "web" prefix: domena/web/app_dev.php and everything works fine.

If you want to change your DocumentRoot write to your administrator to make changes in virtual hosts configuration, just add this line:

```
DocumentRoot /path/to/domain/web
```

Look also at the edit section of the question.

Answer (score 0):

`$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', true)` <=> the prod environment with the debug mod to see the errors, but you don't have access to the profiler to see the logs.
To see the logs, you have to keep this line in `app_dev.php` front controller:

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
```

and then to access to your site like this :

> yourvirtualhost/app_dev.php/
>
> (ex: site.local/app_dev.php/)

Comment: Thanks for reply. But setting this causes blank page as I mentioned. I'm sorry if my question is not clear enough.

Comment: and if you comment `umask(0000);` in your app_dev.php front controller ?